# Slice variable length char array

Tags: arrays, c, string, slice

I have a variable string, that I need to slice into smaller strings, the main string should be treated as a bidimensional array with a certain width and height MxM, and the smaller strings should be cut in blocks of NxN size. So for example, if I have the following string, `char source[17] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNS0"` and his bidimensional size is 4x4, and the size of the smaller blocks are 2x2, the smaller blocks should be `ABEF`, `CDGH`, `IJMN`, `KLSO`.

In other words, the string should be seeing as

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNSO
```

and NxN should be cut from it, like:

```
AB
EF
```

Always with the constraint that these blocks should be linear arrays as the main string.

I have tried with 3 nested for, with the following code, but I didn't know how to calc the index of the main array in order to cut the blocks that way

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char pixelsSource[17] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNS0";
    char pixelsTarget[4][5];

    int Y = 0;
    int X = 0;
    for (int block = 0; block < 4; block++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                pixelsTarget[block][(i * 2) + j] = pixelsSource[(i * 2) + j];
                printf("[%d][%d] = [%d] \n", block, (i * 2) + j, (i * 2));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int block = 0; block < 4; block++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pixelsTarget[block]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `X` and `Y` used for?  Delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I broke this down into a more piece-by-piece way and generalized it for `M` & `N`. Here's the code, with inline comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 4
#define N 2

int main(void)
{
    // source data is an M * M string(plus null terminator)
    char pixelsSource[M * M + 1] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNSO";

    // destination is an array of N*N strings; there are M*M/N*N of them
    char pixelsTarget[(M*M)/(N*N)][N*N + 1];

    // iterate over the source array; blockX and blockY are the coordinate of the top-left corner
    // of the sub-block to be extracted
    for (int blockX = 0; blockX < M; blockX += N)
    {
        for (int blockY = 0; blockY < M; blockY += N)
        {
            int dstWord = blockX/N + blockY;

            // for each letter in the sub-block, copy that letter over to the destination array
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
                {
                    int dstIndex = y*N + x;
                    int srcIndex = (blockY + y)*M + blockX + x;
                    printf("[%d][%d] = [%d]\n", dstWord, dstIndex, srcIndex);
                    pixelsTarget[dstWord][dstIndex] = pixelsSource[srcIndex];
                }
            }

            // null-terminate destination word
            pixelsTarget[dstWord][N*N] = '\0';
        }
    }

    // output
    for (int block = 0; block < (M * M) / (N * N); block++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pixelsTarget[block]);
    }
}
```